# Want to know device name which will support all parameters in FaceDetectionListener

Tags: android

I am using FaceDetectionListener through this code

```
    @Override
    public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
        int id = 0;
        int score = 0;
        Point leftEye = null;
        Point rightEye = null;
        Rect rect = null;
        Point mouth = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
            id = faces[i].id;
            score = faces[i].score;
            leftEye = faces[i].leftEye;
            rightEye = faces[i].rightEye;
            rect = faces[i].rect;
            mouth = faces[i].mouth;



        }
```

for score and Rect i am getting value but for id , leftEye, rightEye, and mouth i am not getting values. I have searched that these parameter are dependent on device.

I want to know device name list which will support these parameter ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could write all manufacturers a letter asking them politely if they do implement this properly or not.

Or you could implement a proper fallback for all those devices that don't handle this properly. If you detect that a device isn't returning an expected value inform the user that his device is not supported (fully).

If you really need that list you could also ask the user at that time if he agrees to share this information with you.

Comment: Or log it as an anonymous analytic event when it fails